# Incrementing random cell in SQL with shared value

Tags: php, sql, adminer

I want to select the lowest value in the 'n' sql column and increment it by 1. If the lowest value is present in multible rows, then I want to choose among those rows at random. For instance, in the example table below where the lowest number is 0 I want to randomly choose between the rows where ID = 1, 2, or 3.

| ID | n |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |

The code below will increment all three rows where n = 0. How do I randomly select just 1? I use Adminer as database.

```
$sql = "UPDATE studycondition SET n=n +1 WHERE n=(SELECT MIN(n) FROM studycondition)";
```

Comment: please tag your dbms

Comment: you can use UPDATE top (1) studycondition ..........

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work... none of the rows will then update

Comment: Without knowing the database you are using, this question cannot be answered.  Please provide that information.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
"UPDATE studycondition SET n=n +1 WHERE n=(SELECT MIN(n) FROM studycondition) limit 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add limit in your inner query and update by id

```
UPDATE studycondition SET n = n + 1 
WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM studycondition order by n asc limit 1)
```